# Always takes 2-3 cranks to start

Tags: starting, dodge, caravan

2000 Caravan 2.4L. If you check my post history, I asked about this vehicle before. I have long since repaired the vehicle, but something that has stuck around: It takes 2-3 attempts to start the car.

It will crank, but usually won't fire until the 3rd attempt. It gets close the 2nd try, and sometimes if I gas it'll start up. Once I start it and then shut it off, it'll fire right back up, cold.

There's pressure at the fuel rail on the first try, so it's getting fuel. I tried taking the MAP out of the picture and it didn't change anything.

It's not a big deal but as someone that likes diagnostics and working on my own stuff, I'd just like to know what's going on here. I would think with spark plugs it would have trouble every time, not just the first time in a day.

Comment: Could you please define what you mean by "an attempt" to start it? Are you turning the key, which starts the engine cranking, cranking, cranking, and it never starts? If so, how long do you hold the key in the start position before you give up? Do you then shut the key off and start again, or what?

Comment: A 23 yr old Caravan will have age related issues, What's actual fuel pressure compared to specs? Lower than ideal fuel pressures may explain several attempts to start until pressure builds up. Was the fuel filter ever replaced (clogged and lowering pressure)? Were spark plugs replaced at recommended intervals? Throttle body cleaned?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 yes, cranking and never starts. Up to 5 seconds. I used to shut it off and let the fuel pump go once again, and then crank. But now I just stop and then start cranking again.

Comment: @FDryer not sure on maintenance, I bought it broke down with pretty much no info besides they didn't use it much. They weren't first owners though, and at 189,000 miles someone sure used it. To answer your questions, I haven't tested the actual pressure at the rail, I only used the valve to see if there was pressure. I replaced the fuel filter with a brand new one. The one that was on it had surface rust and supposedly needed replaced as previous owner was doing that before he broke the line for the fuel pump and the nipple on it.
No clue on plugs, but I do have a new set of plugs + wires. No

Comment: While observing for fuel spraying out the fuel test valve is great for general troubleshooting, lower than normal fuel pressure (clogged fuel filter and/or worn out fuel pump) can contribute to hard starting, Worn out spark plugs, gaps larger than normal, oil fouled, encrusted, can interfere with everyday startup. Old school diagnosing and troubleshooting still trumps new school OBD II readers and scantools but both allow a diyer better troubleshooting compared to some dealers with cookie cutter attitudes without a clue of thinking outside the box (OBD II scantools). Compression test?

Comment: @FDryer I'm aware, and that it isn't really indicated. Fuel doesn't equal enough fuel. Brand new fuel pump and filter, so we can rule those out. Spark plugs are a good idea but no misfire (yet?) which i'd like to see in this issue. I would just go ahead and replace them as I have some new packs, but they're quite annoying on this engine.

I'd checked through with various OBDII tools but they didn't show anything noteworthy.

Possible, sure. However, I'd expect to see more issues if it were comp., no? Runs fine, on and up to 80 MPH. Starts fine after it has been started, too.